# Как подсчитать сумму по столбцу с помощью SQL?

Tags: sql

Помогите, пожалуйста, с SQL-запросом, подсчитывающим сумму по столбцу `cost`, с группировкой по `sale_id` для следующей таблицы `my_data`:

```
id      cost     sale_id   customer_id
---------------------------------------
14030   1736.00     15      1389
14031   1685.00     21      1389
14032   1546.00     21      1389
14033   1233.00     15      1389
14034   1719.00     18      1390
14035   1164.00     19      1390
14036   1736.00     14      1390
14037   1685.00     21      1390
14038   1233.00     14      1390
14039   1546.00     23      1390
14040   1719.00     18      1390
14041   1719.00     18      1390
14042   1719.00     18      1390
14043   1719.00     18      1390
14044   1719.00     18      1390
14045   1090.00     16      1391
14046   1233.00     14      1391
14047   1736.00     15      1391
14048   1685.00     21      1391
14049   1546.00     23      1391
14050   1090.00     16      1391
14051   1090.00     18      1391
14052   1090.00     18      1391
14053   1090.00     18      1391
14054   1090.00     16      1391
14055   1090.00     16      1391
```

со следующим нюансом: в пределах одного и того же `customer_id` учитывается `cost` только первого вхождения `sale_id`. Например, для `sale_id = 18` учитываются только следующие id: 14034, 14051. Сумма по полю `cost` равна 1719 + 1090 = 2809.
Результат должен выглядеть так:

```
sale_id     sum
--------------------
15          3472
21          5055
18          2809
19          1164
14          2969
23          3092
16          1090
```

Comment: @Akina прошу прощения, я ошибся, сейчас поправлю топик. UPD. Сделано. В примере учитывается только id: 14034, 14051.

Comment: @Akina сделано.

Comment: Ну тады я правильно угадал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, sale_id ORDER BY id ASC) rn 
              FROM test )
SELECT sale_id, SUM(cost)
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY sale_id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ea3be62f723dc3f96a56ad0be0fbba4)